Name and notation for "identity times derivative": $x⋅f'(x)$
Let $f:X→X$ be a function and denote by $f'$ its derivative. Is there a standard name and/or notation for the function $g:X→X$ defined by
$$g(x) = x⋅f'(x)$$
where "$⋅$" denotes the multiplication in $X$? As a special case, is there a name and/or notation in the case where $f$ is a polynomial?

What would be the motivation to introduce such a notation? For polynomials it does not cost much ink writing $XP’$. You are thinking of using it for taylor’s approximation?

It is called "Cauchy-Euler operator" (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_operator).

@Abezhiko If that's right, make it an answer.

What's the motivation for this question? E.g. if a probability distribution has cdf $f$, then its expected value is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f'(x) dx$... but I don't think there's a specific name for $g$ in that context because it's just an intermediate step in another calculation.

$d f(x)\over d\log(x)$?

The motivation is a document where I use this a lot. Of course, I can define $g(x) = x⋅f'(x)$ and then use $g$. But I am trying to find a good notation that is easy to remember for the reader, and I wondered if there is a classical one instead of creating one for this document. (For instance, I thought of $f^{[1]}$ or something like this, which reminds the $f^{(1)}$ that is sometimes used for the first derivative.)

See also https://mathoverflow.net/a/402259/454

Using operator notation, one might write $g=xDf$.
In the context of Ordinary Power Series Generating Functions, which include polynomials, the operator $xD$ is sometimes referred to as "the multiply-by-$n$ operator" (see, e.g. Generatingfunctionology).

Thanks, I will have a look in my books on generating functions, to see whether I find some notation there.
